# Rspec spec_helper configuration issue: undefined method `syntax=' for #<RSpec::Mocks::Configuration:> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-mocks

I am trying to confirm a function was called in a controller method with an rspec test.  To do this, I'm following the [relishapp documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/expect-message-using-should-receive) for setting up message expectations.

However, I'm having trouble adding this snippet to `spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.syntax = :should
end
```

While simply `config.mock_with :rspec` was already in the file with no problems caused, adding the snippet above and running rspec causes the following error to appear:

```
You are using WebMock 1.12.3. VCR is known to work with WebMock >= 1.8.0, < 1.12. It may not work with this version.
/Users/user/rails_projects/project/spec/spec_helper.rb:100:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `syntax=' for #<RSpec::Mocks::Configuration:memory_location> (NoMethodError)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I assume the above snippet was within an `RSpec.configure` block?

Comment: The first line of the error in the question body is more or less unrelated to the error, I only included it on the extremely minor chance the WebMock name was causing issues with RSpec's mock.  The second line is the full version of the error in the question title.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I missed the error since it required scrolling to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to execute the configuration option you specified (i.e. `mocks.syntax) is a recently added feature, introduced in RSpec 2.14.0, so you'll get this error until you upgrade to this version or later.

As for the VCR warning, it seems to have been addressed by the latest version of VCR available at github (July 26, 2013), which advertises support through WebMock 1.13. However, the latest released version (2.5.0) is from May, so you'll just have to live with this warning unless you want to pull VCR directly from github.

Comment: I ran `bundle update` which fixed the problem, although the VCR gem was already up-to-date and the `VCR is known to work with WebMock >= 1.8.0...` error still occurs.  I did get updates on `rspec-mocks` and `rspec-expectations` which I think solved the problem.  Still, I'll check this answer off so people know the problem was solved.

Comment: Would you mind checking what version of VCR you've got? I'm guessing that the latest hasn't been pushed to the gem repository. Also, just realized that I missed the error from the title in the rightmost portion of the code snippet. Yes, the rspec update is what likely took care of the problem.

Comment: I am using VCR version 2.5.0

Comment: Ok, I cleaned up the answer a bit. I'll check when the `syntax` method was introduced so that I can include that information as well. BTW, your "accept" was generous under the circumstances. ;-)